# JQ set hundreds div height is not efficient?

Tags: jquery

I use following JQ code to set div equals height in row, but when I load hundreds div, my browser become very slowly.How can I solve this problem?

```
jQuery(function ($){
$(window).bind("scroll", function() { 
$('.list article').equalHeights();
})
})

(function($){  
  $.fn.extend({ equalHeights: function(){
        var top=0;
        var classname=('equalHeights'+Math.random()).replace('.','');
        $(this).each(function(){
             var thistop=$(this).offset().top;
                if (thistop>top) {
                    $('.'+classname).removeClass(classname); 
                    top=thistop;
                }
                $(this).addClass(classname);
                $(this).height('auto');
                var h=(Math.max.apply(null, $('.'+classname).map(function(){ return $(this).outerHeight(); }).get()));
                $('.'+classname).height(h);

        }).removeClass(classname); 
    }       
});})(jQuery);
```

Comment: For better understanding, Please provide a **working demo** (*code snippet,jsfiddle ...*)

Comment: @KishoreSahas:   thank you, demo here:http://t.cn/z0gC2Tq

Comment: Try debouncing your scroll event. Every scroll is fired this function hundreds times.

Comment: @mwl: yes, but I have no idea how to do it

Comment: And second thing - you unnecessery chcek all of articles over and over again. Add to `.list article` custom class, e.g. `.equalHeights` or custom attr, and remove it (this `.equalHeights` class or attr) in your function on elements that already changed. And run it on `$('.list article.equalHeights')` selector to have sure that is fired only on new loaded articles.

Answer (score 0):

Try this link https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

A debounce function does limits the rate at which a function can fire.

Demo :

```js
   function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
     var timeout;
     return function() {
       var context = this,
         args = arguments;
       var later = function() {
         timeout = null;
         if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
       };
       var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
       clearTimeout(timeout);
       timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
       if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
     };
   };

   (function($) {
     $.fn.extend({
       equalHeights: function() {
         var that = this;
         var myEfficientFn = debounce(function(that) {

           var top = 0;
           var classname = ('equalHeights' + Math.random()).replace('.', '');
           $(that).each(function() {
             var thistop = $(that).offset().top;
             if (thistop > top) {
               $('.' + classname).removeClass(classname);
               top = thistop;
             }
             $(that).addClass(classname);
             $(that).height('auto');
             var h = (Math.max.apply(null, $('.' + classname).map(function() {
               return $(this).outerHeight();
             }).get()));
             $('.' + classname).height(h);
           }).removeClass(classname);
         }, 250);

       }
     });
   })(jQuery);
```

The scroll function above will only fire once every quarter of a second instead of as quickly as it's triggered; an incredible performance boost in some cases.